# Can we push/pull message from angular4 using google cloud pubsub?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-pubsub

In Angular4 can we push/pull message directly to google cloud pubsub without calling any service/code in backend ?
If it is possible how can we do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

While technically possible, subscribing to messages via a frontend like Angular would be an anti-pattern for Google Cloud Pub/Sub. If you do that, one of two things will happen:

1. Your frontends will all get messages from the same subscription, which means not every one of them will receive all messages.
2. You will use different subscriptions for each and will quickly run up against the limit of [10,000 subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/quotas#other_limits).

Publishing directly from Angular is also technically possible. For both publish and subscriber, there is a [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/). However, you would have to ensure that your client has the necessary [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started), which would likely mean setting up a service account, using OAuth2 to authenticate from your server, and using that authentication in the client. You probably don't want to do this.

Instead, it is much more typical to run a frontend server that takes requests from your clients and publishes them to Cloud Pub/Sub and likewise, on the subscribe side, receives messages and delivers them to clients as required.

Comment: "...on the subscribe side, receives messages and delivers them to clients as required" How? I see 2 ways - Clients polling or websockets... Is that how it will work? Or are there better alternatives for browser based (ReactJS/ Angular) clients? Thanks in advance!