# Subscribe to Cloud Function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want a way to send simple messages from a Firebase Cloud Function to a client with no cleanup afterward. The data would not be consumable by users. (Rather, it would be used internally by an app.) It is essentially Cloud Function's [onCall](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https#httpsoncall) functionality in reverse.

As far as I can tell, there are a few ways to communicate from the server to the client, but all of them require cleanup of some form:

1. [Subscribe to changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#onsnapshot) to a Firestore document wherein the message is placed: once the message is sent, the document itself is retained until cleanup
2. [Subscribe to changes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-streaming) to a Realtime Database node via the Firebase REST API: same issue as #1

A few anti-patterns:

1. [Pub/sub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45547286/can-we-push-pull-message-from-angular4-using-google-cloud-pubsub): there is a finite number of subscriptions possible
2. [Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/client): for web apps, browsers always display whatever messages they are sent

Is there truly no way to send messages like this? Is there some alternative that I am missing?

Comment: "I want a way to send simple messages from a Firebase Cloud Function to ... an app." How is the consumer app going to receive this message? For example is your app exposing an API endpoint?

Comment: "How is the consumer app going to receive this message?" I'm not tied down to any one design right now. The pattern that I'm looking for is essentially a WebSocket, where the client can receive data from the server without needing to poll. I think that that can be built in the Firebase instance's underlying GCP instance; but I wonder if Firebase has made this easier somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was basically looking for a Firebase version of WebSockets, where clients listen to a server without the need for polling. Firebase seems to have no such functionality. And Firebase Cloud Functions doesn't seem to be designed for this use case, for a few reasons:

1. WebSockets need a single point of ingress. Cloud Functions are designed to deploy dynamically, and idempotently, so that they can scale. The function instances are not designed to communicate with each other. If you could write a Cloud Function acting as a WebSocket server (using `.onRequest`), Cloud Functions' automatic scaling would create multiple functions that could answer requests, but wouldn't speak to one another. No one client could receive all messages being broadcast.
2. WebSocket implementations need a dedicated HTTP port to listen to. Firebase does not provide a way to configure the HTTP ports. They listen to all HTTP traffic on port 80... and that's it.

So the answer is no, you can't subscribe to Cloud Functions because they are too much of a moving target.

That being said, you could build your own WebSocket server from scratch using something like [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/triggering/websockets), and then integrate that third party API into Cloud Functions.